# How do you pull varbinary(MAX) out of SQL Server using DatabaseFactory?

Tags: vb.net, linq, sql-server-2008-r2, binaryfiles

I have a view in SQL Server which gives me varbinary(MAX) data for a PDF copy of a scanned application form (don't ask). Column names in the view include [FileBinary], [Size] and [OriginalFileName].

I use DatabaseFactory throughout the project to pull out data and have not had a problem with types until now. The code to get data from this particular view is:

```
Public Shared Function GetAppFormPDF(studentRefNo As String) As List(Of ProSolutionReportsAppForm)
    Dim db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(Constants.DataBaseConnectionStringProSolutionReports)
    Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [ProSolutionReports].[dbo].[MC_AppFormSSRS_FromPDFScan] WHERE RefNo LIKE '{0}%'", studentRefNo.Trim())
    Return db.ExecuteSqlStringAccessor(Of ProSolutionReportsAppForm)(sql).ToList()
End Function
```

The model it gets pulled into is declared as:

```
Public Property FileBinary As System.Data.Linq.Binary
Public Property Size As Long
Public Property OriginalFileName As String
```

When I hit GetAppFormPDF(), I get told that "The value from column 'FileBinary' cannot be converted to property 'FileBinary' of type 'System.Data.Linq.Binary'."

I created an SQL to Linq DataContext to see how the typing is done there, but (pretty obviously) that's typed to System.Data.Linq.Binary as well and that one works. I also tried typing FileBinary as Byte(), which gives me the data from the rest of the table but sets FileBinary = Nothing.

What do I do to get the varbinary(MAX) data into my model?

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours of investigation I decided that DataFactory is the wrong way to go about this. Instead I did it the way I should have in the first place:

```
    Dim appForms = New List(Of ProSolutionReportsAppForm)

    Dim conn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(Constants.DataBaseConnectionStringProSolutionReports).ConnectionString)
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM [ProSolutionReports].[dbo].[MC_AppFormSSRS_FromPDFScan] WHERE RefNo = @RefNo"

    Dim command As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RefNo", studentRefNo.Trim())
    conn.Open()

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        appForms.Add(New ProSolutionReportsAppForm With {.FileBinary = reader("FileBinary"), _
                                                         .Size = reader("Size"), _
                                                         .ApplicationID = reader("ApplicationID"), _
                                                         .RefNo = studentRefNo,
                                                         .FirstForename = reader("FirstForename"), _
                                                         .Surname = reader("Surname"), _
                                                         .OriginalFileName = reader("OriginalFileName")})
    End While

    reader.Close()
    conn.Close()

    Return appForms
```